# Localizar o próximo valor "menor que" em um array

Tags: php, array

Tenho o seguinte array e preciso localizar o próximo menor valor que o definido em `$valor`:

```
$seq = array(500, 490, 430, 370, 350, 240, 100, 90);
$n_seq = count($seq);
$valor = 400; // ASSUME DIFERENTES VALORES
    if ($valor > $seq[0]){
        $encontrado = $seq[0];
        } else {
        for ($i = $n_seq; $seq[$i] > $valor; $i--) {
        $encontrado = $seq[($i+1)];}
        }
echo "Valor atribuído: ".$valor;
echo "<br>";
echo "Valor encontrado: ".$encontrado;
```

Exemplo: Se `$valor` assume o valor 630, a resposta seria 500.

Se `$valor` assume o valor 500, a resposta seria 490.

Se `$valor` assume o valor 240, a resposta seria 100.

Problema: Não sei se posso encadear `if()` junto a um `for()`, pois a depender dos valores que `$valor` assume tenho um erro de `Undefined offset` com `Undefined variable`.

Alguém poderia me ajugar?

Comment: Você quer dizer: "o maior valor existente no array que seja menor que $valor"? O que você espera como retorno se $valor for 80? Os elementos do array estarão sempre ordenados ou este foi um caso em particular de seu exemplo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui fica uma sugestão:

- Ordenar a array usando o [**sort()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) com opção `1` para fazer sort numérica
- procurar o primeiro numero que é maior ou igual que `$valor` (alternativamente poder-se-ia procurar o valor anterior, ie que é o ultimo a ser menor que `$valor`)

PHP:

```
$seq = array(500, 490, 430, 370, 350, 240, 100, 90);
sort($seq, 1);
$n_seq = count($seq);

$valor = 400; // ASSUME DIFERENTES VALORES
$encontrado = '';
for($i = 0; $i < $n_seq; $i++){
    if ($seq[$i] >= $valor){ // ou usar somente ">"
    $encontrado = $i == 0 ? $seq[$i] : $seq[$i - 1]; 
    break;

    } 
}
if ($encontrado == '' && $valor > end($seq)) $encontrado = end($seq);
if ($encontrado == '' && $valor < $seq[0]) $encontrado = $seq[0];

echo "Valor atribuido: ".$valor;
echo "<br>";
echo "Valor encontrado: ".$encontrado;
```

Comment: Para a sua solução, se utilizo valores fora do intervalo como `600` não obtenho `$encontrado` ou se utilizo um valor que existe no array como `370` não obtenho o `350`, mas sim o próprio `370`.

Comment: @user3486019, para valores fora da array fiz uma coreção ao código, teste de novo. Se não quer usar numeros iguais basta mudar `>=` para `>`. Juntei um comentário na linha específica :)

Comment: OK. Mas agora o código encontra o maior valor subsequente `$valor`, necessito que seja o menor.

Comment: @user3486019, aha, ok. Corrigí para `$encontrado = $seq[$i - 1]; `

Comment: Solução quase perfeita. Se $valor assume valor abaixo do array, exemplo `10`, aparece `Undefined offset`. -- `$seq[$i - 1]` passa a apresentar valor negativo `$seq[-1]`

Comment: @user3486019, corigido.

Comment: Mesmo erro ainda, mas agora se `$valor` assume valores maiores do que o do array, como `600`, tenho como resposta `90` e não o `500`, como esperado.

Comment: @user3486019, desculpe, bug meu, não tinha testado. Corrigi.

Comment: O único problema é quando `$valor` assume valor abaixo que o menor do array, como `10` --> `Notice: Undefined offset: -1 in`

Comment: @user3486019, no código que coloquei agora funciona. Testei com `-600` e deu-me `90`

Comment: Funcionou para encontrar os valores, mas aparece a mensagem `Notice: Undefined offset: -1 in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\askbid.php on line 139`

Comment: que linha é essa?, que código tem lá?

Comment: 139 é a linha do `$encontrado = $seq[$i - 1];`

Comment: Tratei a linha com um if(). Muito obrigado pela ajuda.